# LINQ: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<SomeType, IEnumerable<OtherType>>> selection

Tags: linq

How do I transform this `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyType, IEnumerable<OtherType>>>` into new
sequence of the same type, except I just want `First()` that is in the value (`IEnumerable<OtherType>`). Something like this (pseudo code):

```
  var toReturn = from kv in source
                 let k = new KeyValuePair(kv.Key, kv.Value.First())
                 select k;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm unsure if you want the Value in the new KeyValuePair to be an enumerable of that type or a single element.  Here's both versions

IEnumerable version

```
var toReturn = source.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<SomeType,IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>>(x.Key, x.Value.Take(1));
```

Non-Enumerable Version

```
var toReturn = source.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<SomeType,SomeOtherType>(x.Key,x.Value.First());
```

Comment: Thanks bunch, I needed first version. I actually tried that but forgot to specify the types in KeyValuePair, and was getting an error.

Answer (score 7):

All you're missing is the type of KeyValuePair to use. You could use Jared's lambda expression version, or if you like the query expression syntax:

```
var toReturn = from kv in source
               select new KeyValuePair<MyType, OtherType>(kv.Key, 
                                                          kv.Value.First());
```

If you don't want to explicitly specify the type arguments, you could create your own helper class and use type inference:

```
// Non-generic helper class.
public static class KeyValuePair
{
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Of(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value); 
    }
}
```

at which point your query becomes:

```
var toReturn = from kv in source
               select KeyValuePair.Of(kv.Key, kv.Value.First());
```

or

```
var toReturn = source.Select(kv => KeyValuePair.Of(kv.Key, kv.Value.First());
```

EDIT: Oops - I think I'd misread your question as well. If you want it to be of the exact same type, i.e. with the value being enumerable too, just use `Take(1)` instead of `First()`:

```
var toReturn = source.Select(kv => KeyValuePair.Of(kv.Key, kv.Value.Take(1));
```

(Isn't type inference lovely? :)

Comment: I called my "Of" method "Create" instead, but I really love that approach when I need to manually create KeyValuePairs...

Answer (score 1):

```
var toReturn = source
.ToDictionary(
  kvp => kvp.Key,
  kvp => kvp.Value.Take(1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get a collection of the same type? When you just have the first element, you don't need a collection (`IEnumerable<OtherType>`) but a single value (`OtherType`).

This (like the one you posted) should be correct (you will just need to add generic parameters for the KeyValuePair)

```
  var toReturn = from kv in source select new KeyValuePair<SomeType, OtherType>(kv.Key, kv.Value.First());
```

If you really want to get a collection of the same type, write

```
var toReturn = from kv in source select new KeyValuePair<SomeType, IEnumerable<OtherType>>(kv.Key, new [] { kv.Value.First() });
```

Note: You don't need to give explicit type arguments to the KeyValuePair when you wrap this into a generic function.

```
KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Pair<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value) {
    return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
}
//
var foo = Pair(1, "Hello");
```

Comment: I needed in a same type to be able to pipe it to the same method that handles the other one. This is ordered by date creation desc, and I need to show all or just latest ones.